# XAMPP - phpmyadmin is whitescreen but the localhost is working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Yesterday, my project site is working perfectly but when I tried to start mySQL today I got an error and fixed that by deleting all the unimportant files in the data files. Now I can access the front page of my website but when I clicked on anything it cannot be accessed because my phpmyadmin is white page.

**Apache error log**

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:41.948197 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 18032:tid 648] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:41.969127 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 18032:tid 648] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:41.983083 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18032:tid 648] AH00455: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.4.27 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:41.983083 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18032:tid 648] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Oct  8 2021 10:03:59

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:41.983083 2022] [core:notice] [pid 18032:tid 648] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:41.991890 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18032:tid 648] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 13392

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:42.151357 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 13392:tid 580] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:42.169297 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 13392:tid 580] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Sun Jan 23 19:04:42.185250 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13392:tid 580] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

**mysql error log**

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 555260383; transaction id 758264

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.

Version: '10.4.22-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution

2022-01-23 19:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220123 19:04:42

Comment: And the php error log?

Comment: I don't have php error log

Comment: _Side note:_ Your site has nothing to do with phpmyadmin (which is just a php application, just like yours, for managing mysql databases). So if your site doesn't work, it's not "because" of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Turn on php error reporting then, if there is no log

Comment: @M.Eriksson Hi sir thank you ! I found out that the recent plugin that I installed Wordfence modified my htaccess and now I reverted it using my backup htaccess file. However, the issue that my phpmyadmin is white page still persists.